# NuoDB query statistics

Tags: sql, statistics, query-performance, nuodb

I'm currently doing a research using a TPC-H table and I'm trying to get the running time for 3 queries in NuoDB:

```
  SELECT * FROM LINEITEM 
  SELECT * FROM LINEITEM WHERE L_PARTKEY BETWEEN 1 AND 80000 
  SELECT * FROM LINEITEM WHERE L_PARTKEY BETWEEN 1 AND 80000 OR L_PARTKEY 
  BETWEEN 100001 AND 200000
```

The thing is whenever I run a query, the results come but I guess the database does not store all of the data in memory, but rather keeps its connection open (so when I scroll down through the data results, it refreshes with more data). 
Thus, I cannot retrieve the query running time. I tried setting the *MIN_QUERY_TIME* to 1 so it would be caught in *SYSTEM.QUERYSTATS* but it does not appear there (although I find the query as open in *SYSTEM.CONNECTIONS*, which is why I think the database keeps an open connection rather than storing in-memory).

Is there any kind of solution to fetch all data(as in a select all) and get the query running time?

Is there another way to get this that I'm missing? When I do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LINEITEM
```

it does work and the query goes to *SYSTEM.QUERYSTATS*. I think it is because the database has to go through all rows in order to count and therefore the query finishes, whereas when I do a

```
SELECT *
```

it waits until I "ask" for more data.

I have been trying for days and I could not get into a solution. I even tried different 3rd party tools like DBVisualizer and SQL Workbench but they do not seem to give me the expected results.

I would be really glad if you could give me a hand or at least forward this e-mail to someone that might lead me to a possible solution.

Many thanks.